# Reliably identify the server calling my REST API

Tags: php, rest, server

I have a REST API that I'd like to use with a QA server before a PROD server. Is there a way to determine what server called the API with PHP?

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

... is the closest I've come up with.

```
$remote_host = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if( $remote_host === xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) {
         send repsonse to QA Server
    } elseif($remote_host === aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa ) {
        send response to PROD Server
}
```

Comment: Is it really a quality test if you get different responses depending on the requester? Doing it that way your QA response might be good but the prod could still have problems that you wouldn't catch.

Comment: @jfadich, It would be the same response but if the server that requested it was the QA server then I could QA the response and page that is built around the response. I could create some conditional statements around which server was asking for the data.